# Deserialize JSON Objects in Asp.Net MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, linq, serialization

I'm trying to deserialize an object which was generated by LinqToSql. The user is allowed to edit the data of the object in the view and then it gets posted back to the controller. The edited Data comes in JSON. How does this action have to look like?

Something like...

```
public ActionResult(JsonObject json)
{
    MyClass c = Jsonify(json) as MyClass;
}
```

Is there a nice helpful static class in the framework I'm missing? Or do I have to create a DataContract?

Many thanks

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx)

```
public ActionResult Blah(JsonObject json)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var c = js.Deserialize<MyClass>(json);
    return View(c);
}
```

**EDIT:** Oops...just noticed you are passing an object instead of string....so you will need to use [System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.DataContractJsonSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer.aspx):

```
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
MyClass c = (MyClass)serializer.ReadObject(json);
```

Comment: nice, thanks (and yeeess maybe I was a little to lazy to rtfm ;-))

Comment: Seems to me the DataContractJsonSerializer's ReadObject method only accepts XML readers or streams as input?

Comment: @TedNyberg Yes, that is true: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908232.aspx

Comment: What would be the .NET 5 approach to this?