# Read JSON object in Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have the following JQuery code;

```
var selectedval = $("#PaymentApplication_System").val();
var text = $("#btnSave").val();
var payVal = $("#PaymentApplication_Amount").val();
var dbobj = [{ param: text, value: payVal}];
var jlist = $.toJSON(dbobj);
```

which gives me the following json object;

```
[{"param":"Update Payment","value":"50.00"}]
```

I am using MVC 2. how do I read the values from the object in my controller???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this post can help which is having similar problem:

[Deserialize JSON Objects in Asp.Net MVC Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951640/deserialize-json-objects-in-asp-net-mvc-controller)

Answer (score 2):

MVC 2 does not automatically convert your JSON string to a C# object. You can use the [JavaScriptSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) which is located in System.Web.Script.Serialization. Example:

```
public ActionResult Index(string customerJson)
{
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var customer = serializer.Deserialize<Customer>(customerJson);

    return View(customer);
}
```

This would do pretty good as an extension metod (or put it in a base controller if you have any):

```
public static class ControllerExtensions
{
    public T JsonDeserialize<T>(this Controller instance, string json)
    {
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        return serializer.Deserialize<T>(json);
    }
}
```

You can then use it as:

```
public ActionResult Index(string customerJson)
{
    var customer = this.JsonDeserialize<Customer>(customerJson);

    return View(customer);
}
```

Comment: FYI MVC3 does include a JsonValueProviderFactory that automatically deals with this.

Comment: @murki Yep, i know. This question was for MVC2 which does not deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

MVC 2 does not convert JSON objects to Models while MVC 3 does.

You have to use [JSON.net](http://json.codeplex.com/).