# Convert table data to Json in Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to send data to controller i tried in string fromat but after certain limit it is not accepting data...so  i thought to convert it to json and send...or if there is any other way to send more data by Ajax please suggest me,plese tell me how can i convert my data to json format and how to convert it into string in controller,....

```
var param = "&tbl=" + tbldata;
        param = param + "&tblheader=" + tblheader;

        var request = $.ajax({
            url: '../rep/send?'+param,
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            dataType: 'text',
            contentType: 'application/text; charset=utf-8'
        });

[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult SendReport(string tbl, string tblheader)
{

}
```

Comment: please suggest me any limit that i can pass while data sending by ajax in jquery...\

Answer (score 0):

If that tbldata is string then you can use the function called **JSON.stringify(string)** and in that Ajax dataType should be json.

For your reference :[Difference between JSON.stringify and JSON.parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17785592/difference-between-json-stringify-and-json-parse)

Comment: this is not my problem i already tried this when i am sending data in string form it is accepting up to certain limit like param.lenth - 1576 likewise after that it is crashing my code so i thought convert it into json and send it to controller...if you have any solution so i can send more data in string form also pelase let me know

Comment: Then i hope you should modify web.config <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxxx" /> property

Comment: i tried now this also not working man plese suggest something else

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following in your web.config file.

```
 <configuration>
   <system.web>
     <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="xxxx" />
   </system.web>
 </configuration>
```

The default value for `maxRequestLength` is 4096 (4MB).

Try setting something that is larger that 4MB. That may work for you.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @user2996030 check the browser console. There might be some errors with the ajax request

Answer (score 0):

passing data in url has a limit depending on navigator ([Example](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html))

its better to pass it in request body :

```
var request = $.ajax({
   url: '../rep/send',
   type: 'POST',
   cache: false,
   dataType: 'json',
   data: {
          tbl: tbldata,
          tblheader : tblheader 
   },
   contentType: 'application/text; charset=utf-8'
});
```

**Edit**

create Model :

```
[DataContract]
public class ReportModel
{
    [DataMember]
    public string tbl {get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string tblheader {get; set; }
}
```

modify controller :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult SendReport([FromBody] ReportModel data)
{

}
```

Comment: @user2996030 I ve edited my post, reflecting something i'm using and working.

Comment: it is only way to accept json data to controller please sugeest me any other way if so?

Comment: plese give me perfect solution

Answer (score 0):

If you will use `json` (that is a good choice) you need to understand [javscript object structure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects), [serialization](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-json-serialization/) in client side and [deserialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2951640/deserialize-json-objects-in-asp-net-mvc-controller) in server side.

Answer (score 0):

remember to encode the data.

in javascript:

```
  var sJsonData = JSON.stringify({your data});
  ......
  contentType:"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
  data: "sJsonObject=" + encodeURIComponent(sJsonData),
```

so your case would look like:

```
        url: '../rep/send',
        type: 'POST',
        data: "sJsonObject=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(para)),
        contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8',
        ...
```

server side:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ajaxProcess(string sJsonObject = "")
string sUnescapeJsonData = System.Uri.UnescapeDataString(sJsonObject);
```